# Firebase realtime database rules don't allow anonymous-authenticated users

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a simple web app with a Firebase realtime database, and Firebase auth.
My db rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so only an authenticated user can read/write their own user record.
But when I allow anonymous authentication, anonymous users cannot write their own profile record even though they have a UID and are writing to the correct record. I get a Firebase "PERMISSION DENIED" error.

It all works fine with email+password-authenticated users. To be clear, logging in with email+password provider works fine, but logging in anonymously (with the anonymous provider) does not allow write access.

I am testing this in the `onAuthStateChanged()` callback, so I know the user is valid:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
  try {
    // ignore token refresh events
    if (user && currentUID === user.uid)
      return

    if (user) {
      currentUID = user.uid
      // Create user record and update last login
      const db = getDatabase()
      const userRef = ref(db, 'users/' + user.uid)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(user))
      if (true) { // <<<<<<<<<<< THIS IS WHERE I GET "permission denied"
        update(userRef, {
          email: user.email || '-none-',
          uid: user.uid,
          lastLogin: serverTimestamp()
        })
          .catch(err => handleError(err))
      }
      on_sign_in(user)
    } else {
      currentUID = null
      // User is signed out
      on_sign_out()
    }

  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error, error.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: At first things both the code and rules look fine. Are you saying that it works when you sign in with another provider, but not when you sign in anonymously?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added a note in the question to clarify that it works with email+password provider but not when signing in anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but the SDK and code seem to work as expected for me. I'm posting my minimal non-repro here, in hopes it'll help you find the difference between your non-working code and my working example.

My code:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log("User signed in", user);

    const dbRef = ref(db, "77153837");
    const userRef = child(dbRef, user.uid);

    set(userRef, false).then(() => {
      console.log("Wrote to db");
    });
  }
})
signInAnonymously(auth);
```

And the rules I use:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "77153837": { 
      "$uid": { 
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

In these the `77153837` is the ID of the question you posted here. It has no meaning for the problem beyond that.

You can see the entire code and run it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-v9-rtdb-anonymous-writes